# FindViewById for Chronometer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use a Chromoeter to display the elapsed time in an Android.Widget. However, as I am using AppWidgetProvider, I am unable to use FindViewById.

I get this error: The name 'FindViewById' does not exist context.

```
public class WidgetClass : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            var me = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(WidgetClass)).Name);
            appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context, appWidgetIds));
        }

        private RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget);
            UpdateData(widgetView);
            return widgetView;
        }

        private void UpdateData(RemoteViews widgetView)
        {
            Chronometer mChronometer = FindViewById<Chronometer>(Resource.Id.chronometer1);
            mChronometer.Base = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime();
            mChronometer.Start();   
        }
```

How can I set the base for the Chronometer in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Try to invoke the line `widgetView.FindViewById<Chronometer>(Resource.Id.chronometer1);`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I get this error message: RemoteViews' does not contain a definition for 'FindViewById' and no accessible extension method 'FindViewById' accepting a first argument of type 'RemoteViews' could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FindViewById` is from the namespace `Android.Views.View`, create an [using alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) for the namespace:

```
using AView = Android.Views.View
...
Chronometer mChronometer = AView.FindViewById<Chronometer>(Resource.Id.chronometer1);
```